# Videojs custom TextTrackDisplay not working

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I have requirement in my project to customize player controls. I found a lot documentation how to make it possible, except TextTrackDisplay component. For some reason this component has been rendered by videojs, but rendered code seems have no clue about any existing text tracks of standard hls stream (bip-bop).

[image]

I've created sample of code where play button successfully customized, but TextTrackDisplay wasn't for some reason...

https://codepen.io/jurij-sergeewich-gerc/pen/xxxwPmN

```
class Player extends React.Component {
  init = (videoRef) => {
    const videoJsOptions = {
      controls: false,
      html5: {nativeTextTracks: false},
    };

    const player = videojs(videoRef, videoJsOptions, () => {
      const type = 'application/x-mpegURL';
      const src = 'https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8'
      player.pause();
      player.src({type, src});
      player.play();

      this.connectPlayButton(player);
      this.connectTextTracks(player);
    });
  }

  connectPlayButton = (player) => {
    const selector = '[data-play-btn]';
    const allElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    allElements.forEach((box) => {
      const PlayToggle = videojs.getComponent('PlayToggle');
      const playToggle = new PlayToggle(player);
      box.appendChild(playToggle.el());
    });
  };

  connectTextTracks = (player) => {
    const selector = '[data-text-tracks]';
    const allElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    allElements.forEach((box) => {
      const TextTrackDisplay = videojs.getComponent('TextTrackDisplay');
      const textTrackDisplay = new TextTrackDisplay(player);
      box.appendChild(textTrackDisplay.el());
    });
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video ref={this.init} className="video-js-video">
        </video>
        <div data-play-btn></div>
        <div data-text-tracks></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Player/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Could any one help me please :))

Answer (score 0):

I just was tired at night yesterday, this is stupid, but for show "cc" in control panel, we need to use not 'TextTrackDisplay' component but 'SubtitlesButton'.